# Change Page Template Oracle

Tags: oracle, templates, oracle-apex

I'm trying changing  template in one page of my application, but the problem is when i change the template in page 1 (for example), the other pages change also (except login).

How i can solve my problem? If you know, please tell me the steps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create another new template for pages other than page 1, and assign the new template to that page in Page Attribute->Display Attribute->Page Template->

Hope this will help.